# Convert pixel data (in txt file) in libsvm format

Tags: python, libsvm

I am trying to perform a prediction with libsvm for the recognition of a specific object in an image. I was able to convert my images using the sobel operator and I stored the pixel value of one of the image into a txt file.
So, I have a txt file that looks like that:

```
14 18 0

173 176 145

175 177 155

20 21 7

19 18 13

9 7 8

3 1 4

3 1 2

5 4 2

1 0 0

[...]
```

My problem is that I am not really familiar with the libsvm data format so I was wondering: how do I modify this file using python in order to make it usable with the libsvm?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

A converter shouldn't be so difficult but even better is not saving to txt! You probably don't need this intermediate step. You can input your image data to libsvm directly using libsvm python bindings or (my recomendation) [scikits](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/), see for example:

http://scikit-learn.org/0.13/auto_examples/plot_digits_classification.html

Note: Scikits uses libsvm.

Comment: @elyase how about using Java (libsvm), how to bind image to training data?

Comment: @OSIFY, would you mind asking a new question with more details about what you want to do? I know it can be a little longer but you will surely get quicker answers because more people(not only me) will be looking into it.

Comment: @elyase I already did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666851/how-to-train-image-pixel-data-in-libsvm-format-to-use-for-recognition-with-jav